# multiple accounts in .netrc not working if encrypted?

Tags: git, authentication, encryption, .netrc

### WORKING NOW - add github.com twice

After debugging more by adding the `-d` flag to `netrc` in the credential helper, I found it wasn't matching the usernames in the `<USER>@github.com` in the remote URLs.

Because some SO answers use the 1 line format for netrc, I tried adding `machine github.com` twice… and it worked ‍♀️

```
machine github.com
  login PERSONAL-USER
  password PAT1
machine github.com
  login WORK_USER
  password PAT2
```

#### Use case

I have a situation that is maddening because everything works when I have a `.netrc` file, but breaks as soon as it's encrypted to `.netrc.gpg`. I've used this setup for years, decrypting it on the fly with my YubiKey and `git config credential.helper 'netrc -f ~/.netrc.gpg -v'`.

I recently had to adjust the setup because of work:

- I have a personal GitHub account
- I have a 2nd work account because my employer uses GitHub Enterprise Cloud.

So I have a `.netrc` file that needs 2 logins for 1 host like this:

```
machine github.com
  login PERSONAL-USER
  password PAT1
  login WORK_USER
  password PAT2
```

Yes, my personal username has a dash `-` in it. My work username has an underscore `_`. Would this make a difference?

The weird thing is that it works if it's unencrypted. But as soon as I encrypt it, it breaks.

- `.netrc` ✅ works
- `.netrc.gpg` ❌ cannot authenticate

When I have this file as an unencrypted `.netrc` file in my home directory, it works  fine.
However, as soon as I encrypt it, it breaks and says **repository not found**, like this:

```
$ git push origin :test2
using gpg for GPG operations
Using GPG to open /Users/redacted/.netrc.gpg: [gpg --decrypt /Users/redacted/.netrc.gpg]
gpg: encrypted with rsa4096 key, ID ED826C8A57E12FC3, created 2018-05-27
      "Julie Ng <REDACTED>"
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/julie-ng/REDACTED.git/' not found
```

#### Other things I tried

**Set contexts**

I also tried specifying which accounts to use. So my global git config via `~/.gitconfig` has these lines in it per [official git documentation on configuring contexts](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)

```
[credential]
        helper = netrc -f ~/.netrc.gpg -v
        user = <PERSONAL-USER>
        useHttpPath = true
[credential "https://github.com/<WORK_USER>/*"]
        user = <WORK_USER>
[credential "https://github.com/<WORK_OSS>/*"]
        user = <PERSONAL-USER>
[credential "https://github.com/<PERSONAL-USER>/*"]
        user = <PERSONAL-USER>
```

**Specify user in git remote**

I even tried

```
# personal repo - doesn't work
git remote set-url origin https://<PERSONAL-USER>@github.com/...
```

and it does not work. I did the same for a work specific repo.

```
# work repo - works?!
git remote set-url origin https://<WORK_USER>@github.com/<WORK_USER>...
```

And the work works fine.

**Clear all caches, etc**

- I use a mac, but not the osx keychain. Being paranoid, I confirmed nothing's there.
- I also ran `git credential-cache exit` between tests
- And I also ran `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye` between tests

I'm at wits' end trying to figure this out. Does anyone have any idea why this would work with a unencrypted `.netrc` file but not when encrypted to `.netrc.gpg`??